# Preventing Windows from (scheduled) shutting down

Tags: windows-7

It is a desktop computer, and every morning (I start around 08h) it shuts down some 10-15 minutes after turning it on, and every evening it shuts down at exactly 20h.

This morning I came back later than usual, and noticed since I first turned it on around 09h, it didn't shut down, so I came to realize it could also be some process, the result of which it shuts down in the morning, but when skipped, it waits until the evening.

In cmd, the result of *shutdown /a* gave an 1116 message.

Could anybody give an explanation, and guidelines how to turn off that behaviour?

Comment: 1116 means that no scheduled shutdown was in progress. The system itself did not schedule it using the shutdown.exe executable. Therefore it is being done _manually_ at that given time. 2 possible causes: A scheduled task is ordering to do that (look through the list in Task Scheduler); OR software is ordering a shutdown by means of or other than shutdown.exe. It is too coincidental for this to be happening every 12 hrs at a specific time, that is way to convenient. It is likely you will find something in task scheduler.